# Upgrading from Python 2.6 to 2.7 isn't working

Tags: python, frameworks, version

Using a mac 10.6, I tried downloading and installing python 2.7. Although the installer finished, and python 2.7 is in the Applications folder, the framework folder still hasn't changed, and the latest is 2.6.

When I run a python script I right-click to choose Python Launcher(2.7)(default), but I've included the lines

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

In my script, and that shows

```
2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)
```

What's going on?

ALSO IDLE 2.7 isn't working (claiming connection is blocked), but 2.6 does.

Answer (score 2):

It's dangerous to upgrade your preinstalled Python because some Mac programs rely on that specific version. You should use [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) so that you don't break dependencies. And to start it, type:

```
python2.7
```

in the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can always alias it through your terminal settings or your .bash settings file so that every time you run the command `python` terminal runs `python2.7` instead.

Type `alias python='python2.7'` into your terminal to get started.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is to make sure /usr/local/bin(where binaries that are not part of your system and/or a package manager are installed) is before /usr/bin in your $PATH, same for all the rest of /usr/local/*.

The easiest way to upgrade python is probably [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), it's basically a great package manager for OSX (like macports/fink but better).

Failing that, you could try manually uninstalling it (look in /usr/local/), and then try again. The best way to do that is probably virtualenv, where you can have a python install with write permissions for you user(easy to install modules).